# Best wifi channel I should pick for my area

Tags: wireless-networking

Okay so after looking at the networks in my area here is what I got.

http://www.mediafire.com/view/yors8fuyeb889vi/scrn-53e2687d.png

I along with some other networks are on channel 1.

Based on that should I change my channel to 6 or just leave it as is.

Comment: It likely won't make a difference, but change it, and see if it does.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what is available and used in your surrounding, 6 is the best option. There will be some interference from the 2 and 3 channels, but only slightly. You'd have more problems with that from channel 1. On channel 11 there is a lot of usage too. The table you show doesn't clearly give the signal strength (it is there, but its hard to see in one glimp which is the best channel.

Answer (score 0):

Some months ago i also had to to the same thing.
I used [Wifi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer)  and walked with my phone around the places that wiFi would mostly be used.

In your case i would choose channel 8 or 9.

Comment: No. Channels 8 or 9 is a bad thing to do. Stick to 1, 6 or 11. Dunno why? Type in google: Wifi 1 6 11

Comment: Interesting! I learned something new today!

Comment: Well I changed to 6 and noticed a slight increase in speed